# WebClient doesn't show relative pathed images or css inside of iframe

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this bit of code and it seems to work well at fetching the websites HTML which I can stick inside an iframe. The problem I have is how would I get it to show images and css from sites when the path for those are relative?

```
public void ProcessRequest()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";

    Stream data = client.OpenRead(baseUrl);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(s);
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: You have to fetch them as well and have them served from your own site.

Comment: Use something like HtmlAgilityPack to fetch the script and link tags and then use webclient to read and store their content. Keep in mind that what you try to achieve is hard.